# Jenkins plugin to make REST calls and fetch output in JSON

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

Please suggest a plugin or an approach to achieve the following in Jenkins declarative pipeline.

Comment: Have you looked at [HTTP Request](https://plugins.jenkins.io/http_request), in conjunction with [Conditional Build Step](https://plugins.jenkins.io/conditional-buildstep/) ?

Comment: If you manage to find a plugin, you can test it by creating an API at wirespec.dev

Comment: @IanW Thanks. I have been exploring HTTP Request plugin, seems to fit the requirement. However not sure if Conditional Build Step supports groovy. That is something i need to explore. A plugin with groovy declarative support would be great.

Comment: If you have linux jenkins slave, you can restrict your pipeline run on linux slave by label, then you can use `curl` to call rest api.

Comment: The Conditional Build Step leverages [Run condition](https://plugins.jenkins.io/run-condition/) which supports many options, but not groovy (sh and cmd, yes). However, I'm reasonably certain yoy can craft a regular expression to match current date to a string in the response. If there is a match, abort the job. Not sure about pipeline support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any plugin per se, as you can use e.g. `curl`:

```
def calendar_url = "https://calendarific.com/api/v2/holidays?&api_key=758f54db8c52c2b500c928282fe83af1b1aa2be8&country=IN&year=2020"

def curl_output = sh returnStdout: true, script: "curl -s ${calendar_url}"
```

You can convert it to json with [readJson utility](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace):

```
def holidays = readJson text: curl_output
for (holiday in holidays.response.holidays) {
    def holiday_date = holiday.date.iso
    println holiday_date
}
```

Defining the current date and bailing out of the build is left as an exercise for the implementor :)